Flutter Localization can not chanage language (using riverpod)
I am using the localization package with Riverpod. However, when I change my locale variable, the application language does not change. How can I fix this?
changing lacale variable:
  if (locale != null) {
        ref.read(languageProvider).setLanguage = locale;
      }

MaterialApp:
    final languageProvider2 = ref.watch(languageProvider);
    locale: languageProvider2.language,

LanguageRiverpod:
 class LanguageRiverpod extends ChangeNotifier{
  Locale _language = Locale('en');
  get language => _language;
  set setLanguage(Locale language) {
    _language = language;
    print(_language);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

